# How can I select and edit mysql results based on which row is clicked?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, post

**Before I start, I'd just like to explain that I'm aware of the deprecation in MySQL and SQL Injections. This is purely for practice purposes.**

I have a simple table with results from a mysql database using

```
mysql_fetch_assoc();
```

and then using a While loop to display the results in a table.
I'm using Twitter-Bootstrap as a CSS Framework and to also handle the Modals explained further on.

Here is the output

[image: Table]

Now what I wish to do is to trigger a Modal using the edit button which will contain that specific row's data in a form. Getting the modal to trigger is not a problem, it's displaying the specific row's data within the modal dependent on which row has had the edit button clicked. As for the Form, there will be 4 `<input>`'s  with a submit button at the bottom of the Modal to update the results in the database. I will most likely be handling that with a $.POST/Ajax method rather than php as it'd be nice to refresh the table without having to reload the page after the modal has closed.

I'm confident in being able to update the results but it's just getting "$(this)" 's data to be displayed dependant on which result wants to be edited.

Here is an image of the modal when triggered by clicking on the edit button.
[image: modal view]

How could I do this?

Here's my code.

```
<table class="table users table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { $id=$row['id']; $name=$row['name']; $desc=$row['description']; $quantity=$row['quantity']; $price=$row['price']; echo "<tr id='data-form' >
<td>$id</td>
<td>$name</td>
<td>$desc</td>
<td>$quantity</td>
<td>". '$'. "$price</td>
<td><button href='#Edit' data-toggle='modal' class='btn btn-success'>Edit</button>
</td>
<td><button class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button>
</td>                                                   
</tr>"; } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>



<div id="Edit" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
                    <h3>Edit Item</h3>

            </div>
            <div id="inner-data" class="modal-body">
                <label>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="test" id="name">
                <br>
                <label>Description:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="test" id="description">
                <br>
                <label>Quantity:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="test" id="quantity">
                <br>
                <label>Price:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="test" id="price">
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">  <a data-dismiss="modal" id="updateResults" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" href="#">Save</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Strawberry Perhaps that wasn't the best way to word it. I have now re-worded it.

Comment: what do you want to do? submit the data through AJAX?

Comment: @ferozakbar Maybe, I think I'm leaning more towards using PHP now I think about it.